# ajax get response from php echo not working

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to get response from php echo statement but I am not getting any response, my code seems fine but I don't know why it doesn't work

```
test.php
<?php echo "test" ?>

dashboard.php
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadlink(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Hello"),
                document.getElementById("links").innerHTML=response;
            }
        });
    }

    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(function(){
        loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
    }, 5000);
</script>

<div id="links"></div>
```

I am testing on my localhost, I do not get any response when I open the page

Comment: `<?php echo test?>` is invalid PHP and will not compile or run

Comment: Try `<?php echo 'test'; ?>`

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?
Does it compile (see above comment, unless it's a typo when you copied into SO, that's probably you issue)? Does it give you bad results?  Please read How to Ask in the Help section.  *Always* include full error messages, and clear descriptions of why/how code isn't producing your expected/desired results.  "It doesn't work is not helpful" for us to quickly diagnose your issue, in most cases - it always makes it quicker for us.

Comment: I have edited the question, I am actually testing on localhost using xammp

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the error, I debugged using google chrome, the code is correct but apparently i did not declare java script before the code